# Package providing fully expandable conditionals

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion, programming

Is there a package providing a collection of fully expandable conditionals like this one:

```
\newcommand\myif@num[1]
{\ifnum#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
```

Background: Let's say I want to program an expandable recursive macro `\foo` which contains a nested use of `\ifnum`. Then this could look like this:

```
\def\foo#1#2%
{%
  ... some stuff ...
  \ifnum\bar=\z@% exit condition
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobbletwo
   \else
    \ifnum\baz>\quux% another exit condition
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobbletwo
     \else
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\foo
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter{\the\numexpr...}{stuff}%
}
```

But even this won't work because the last `\fi` is not always destroyed. So off to `\romannumeral` trickery...

With the above macro this conditional looks like this:

```
\def\foo#1#2%
{%
  ... some stuff ...
  \myif@num{\bar=\z@}
  {}
  {%
    \myif@num{\baz>\quux}
    {}
    {\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\the\numexpr...}{stuff}}%
  }%
}
```

Much cleaner, isn't it?

Comment: Do you want  _just_ the conditionals, or conditionals plus 'other stuff'? I assume what you want here is 'conditionals with LaTeX syntax', similar to for example `\@ifpackageloaded` in how they behave?

Comment: @JosephWright Well the use case is that I need exactly this one in one of my packages, but I hate redefining generic stuff, so the minimal "canonical" package providing this would suffice.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't care so much for the syntax, but for convenient expandable programming without the need to desintegrate a lot of leftover `\fi`s.

Comment: The classic in this area (and one of the first uses I think of that `\expandafter` trick (which didn't appear in plain or latex2.09) is  Alan Jeffrey's `lambda.sty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the hint. But it has only `\Lessthan` predefined, and I was looking for a more complete collection. I wanted to avoid having to define such basics myself ;-)

Comment: It's not stated in the question, but I assume we can use an e-TeX solution to allow integer expressions, not just single integers?

Comment: The [texapi](http://ctan.org/pkg/texapi) package defines a lot of conditionals, most of the expandable IIRC.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for the hint. But the documentation talks a lot about execution and very little about expansion, so I don't trust it ;-)

Comment: I must confess I have never really used it myself…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a package providing *only* the tests requests, but the two obvious candidates for this as part of a more general toolkit are [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel). The `etoolbox` package is not as big in scope as `expl3`, and uses a more 'traditional' TeX syntax. In the case in question, you would have

```
\newcommand{\myif@num}[3]{%
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{#2}{#3} % eg "1 + 1", "=" and "2" would take the TRUE branch
}
```

where the two integer values are expressions but must be given separately.

The LaTeX3 `expl3` package provides an entire programming language, of which expandable tests are only part. A suitable definition here would be

```
 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \cs_new_eq:NN \my@ifnum \int_compare:nTF
 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

as `\int_compare:nTF` takes a single argument (such as `1 + 1 = 2`) and evaluates the test to absorb either the TRUE or FALSE branch as needed. (Note that there is also a slightly faster `\int_compare:nNnTF`, which like `\ifnumcomp` needs three arguments.) The LaTeX3 conditionals are available as 'only TRUE' or 'only FALSE' versions, *e.g.* `\int_compare:nT`, to avoid needing empty groups.

---

Perhaps at a tangent to what is wanted, but you might also take a look at [`boolexpr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/boolexpr) for expandable Boolean expressions. Both `etoolbox` and `expl3` also do this, but the implementations and interfaces are different.

Comment: Great, `etoolbox` seems to be just what I need! (only used `\patchcommand` so far ;-)